# Obtain a list of the 143.859 Unicode Standard, Version 13.0.0 characters

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

Is it possible to obtain a list of all the 143,859 characters included in the 13.0.0 version of Unicode?
I'm trying to print these 143,859 characters in python but was unable to find a comprehensive list of all the characters.

Comment: Just `print(chr(i))` for integers i....

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be a question about programming. You can get this information by downloading it off unicode.org.

Comment: @wim it won't work quite like that because not all code points are assigned.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think that is still on-topic and about programming (e.g. "how can I write a program to obtain the 143,859 characters"), even if that answer involved a program which download the data from unicode.org..

Comment: How do you intend to print them?  It's quite unlikely you have a font that includes all 144,000 code points.

Comment: @TimRoberts [GNU Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont/index.html) has glyphs for all the printable ones in the basic multilingual plane.

Answer (score 2):

To obtain a list of 143,859 characters you must [exclude the same categories the unicode consortium has excluded](https://www.unicode.org/versions/stats/charcountv13_0.html) in order to come up with that count.

```
import sys
from unicodedata import category, unidata_version

chars = []
for i in range(sys.maxunicode + 1):
    c = chr(i)
    cat = category(c)
    if cat == "Cc":  # control characters
        continue
    if cat == "Co":  # private use
        continue
    if cat == "Cs":  # surrogates
        continue
    if cat == "Cn":  # noncharacter or reserved
        continue
    chars.append(c)

print(f"Number of characters in Unicode v{unidata_version}: {len(chars):,}")
```

Output on my machine:

```
Number of characters in Unicode v13.0.0: 143,859
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is probably to read the [UnicodeData.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/13.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) file as recommended by @wim in a comment below, then expand all the ranges that are marked off by `<..., First>` and `<..., Last>` in the second column, e.g., expand

```
3400;<CJK Ideograph Extension A, First>;Lo;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
4DBF;<CJK Ideograph Extension A, Last>;Lo;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
```

to

```
3400
3401
3402
...
4DBD
4DBE
4DBF
```

I haven't checked, but I'm guessing this would give you a pretty complete list.

Below are some other suggestions I made earlier, some of which could be useful.

**Other Ideas**

You can make a start with the [Unicode Character Name Index](https://www.unicode.org/charts/charindex.html), which is linked from the list of [Unicode 13.0 Character Code Charts](https://www.unicode.org/charts/). However, that table has significant gaps and repetitions, e.g., all Latin capital letters are lumped under `0041` (`A`) and the group is identified a few different ways. Actually, the table is pretty incomplete -- it only has 2.759 unique codes.

Keying off of @wim's comment on the original post, another option might be to take a look at the source code for Python's unicodedata module. [unicodename_db.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/unicodename_db.h) has some lists of codes that are read by `_getucname` in [unicodedata.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/unicodedata.c). It looks like `phrasebook` may have a nearly complete list of codes (188,803 items), but possibly munged in some way (I don't have time to figure out the lookup/offset mechanism right now). In addition to those, Hangul syllables and unified ideographs are processed as ranges, not looked up from the phrasebook.

Comment: [UnicodeData.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/13.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) might be more complete.

Comment: @wim, yes, [UnicodeData.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/13.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) has 33,907 entries and the [Unicode Character Name Index](https://www.unicode.org/charts/charindex.html) only has 2759 unique codes.

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY file you need is DerivedName.txt, available in the Unicode Character Database (UCD). The file for version 14.0 can be found [here](https://www.unicode.org/Public/14.0.0/ucd/extracted/DerivedName.txt).

```
# PyPI package unicode_charnames
# Supports version 14.0 of the Unicode Standard
from unicode_charnames import charname, UNICODE_VERSION

assigned = []
control = []
private_use = []
surrogate = []
noncharacter = []
reserved = []
for x in range(0x110000):
    name = charname(chr(x))
    if not name.startswith("<"):
        assigned.append(x)
    elif name.startswith("<control"):
        control.append(x)
    elif name.startswith("<private"):
        private_use.append(x)
    elif name.startswith("<surrogate"):
        surrogate.append(x)
    elif name.startswith("<noncharacter"):
        noncharacter.append(x)
    else:
        reserved.append(x)

print(f"# Unicode {UNICODE_VERSION}")
print(f"# Code points assigned to an abstract character: {len(assigned):,}")
print(f"# Unassigned code points: {len(reserved):,}")
print( "# Code points with a normative function")
print(f"#   Control characters     : {len(control):>7,}")
print(f"#   Private-use characters : {len(private_use):>7,}")
print(f"#   Surrogate characters   : {len(surrogate):>7,}")
print(f"#   Noncharacters          : {len(noncharacter):>7,}")

# Unicode 14.0.0
# Code points assigned to an abstract character: 144,697
# Unassigned code points: 829,768
# Code points with a normative function
#   Control characters     :      65
#   Private-use characters : 137,468
#   Surrogate characters   :   2,048
#   Noncharacters          :      66
```